# Uniqueness for an elliptic problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

I want to prove the uniqueness of the solution of the following problem:
$$\eqalign{
  &  - d\Delta u + u = {u^p}{\text{ in }}\Omega   \cr 
  & u > 0{\text{ in }}\Omega   \cr 
  & \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \nu }} = 0{\text{ on }}\partial \Omega  \cr} $$
with $\Omega$ is a bounded open in $R^n$, d$>0$ and $p>1$.
I tried the classical methods but without any success. Thanx.

Comment: If there is uniqueness, then it has to be constantly one. So showing uniqueness is the same as showing it to be 1 (not sure if that is useful).

Comment: What is your sign convention for the Laplacian?

Comment: Looks like section 3 of [this paper](http://doi.org/10.2307/2000473) investigates (a slight generalization of) this problem. Seems that the uniqueness holds only for certain ranges of $d,p$ depending on the dimension and the spectrum of $\Delta.$

Comment: Thank you guys.